# How do I get this binding expression?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

The following is my XAML code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModel.Rows}"
              x:Name="LView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="401" Margin="10,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="504">

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Expressions" 
                                Width="250" 
                                Header="Expression"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Expression}">
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Tele" 
                                Width="50" 
                                Header="In Tele?">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="telCheck" 
                                      DataContext="{Binding}"
                                      IsEnabled="True"        
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=Tel, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"></CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

How do I get the binding expression for `telCheck` (i.e., the checkbox's `isChecked` property)? Earlier in my code, for a `TextBox` named `NameBox`, I did the following:

```
var be = NameBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
be.updateSource();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the UpdateSourceTrigger to **PropertyChanged**, then the Tel property should have the value.